# Tengo un problema de extraer el texto de un label y mostrarlo por consola

Tags: java, android, app

estoy intentando de automatizar una app la cual nesecito que me lea un label y su texto, y que este sea mostrado por consola la app està de la siguiente forma.

```
DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
    //@BeforeMethod
    protected void setUp(String deviceName, String versionAndroid ) throws MalformedURLException {
      dc.setCapability("deviceName", deviceName);
      dc.setCapability("platformVersion", versionAndroid);
      dc.setCapability("platformName","Android");
      dc.setCapability("automationName","Appium");
      dc.setCapability("appPackage", "com.ripley.banco.peru");
        dc.setCapability("appActivity", "md50120b660b57d6504f7403c716c787885.MainActivity");
        //driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), dc);
        driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), dc);
        driver.setLogLevel(Level.INFO);
    }
```

este es el mètodo:

```
protected void prueba(String equipo,String versionSO) throws MalformedURLException {
        setUp(equipo, versionSO);
        waitSleep(2);
        //if(assertEquals(driver.findElement(Constantes.txtTipoDeDocumento)) == "Tipo de documento"){
        AndroidElement ele = (AndroidElement) driver.findElement(By.xpath(Constantes.txtTipoDeDocumento));
        //(RemoteElement)driver.findElement(By.xpath(Constantes.txtTipoDeDocumento));
        System.out.println(ele.getText());

            }
```

al final me lanza este error.

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement cannot be cast to
>   io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement  at
>   pe.abs.absRipley.prueba(absRipley.java:827)   at
>   pe.casos.TestEscenario1.caso46(TestEscenario1.java:39)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:661)   at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:869)    at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1193)  at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:126)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:744)    at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)   at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)   at
>   org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
>
> ===============================================
>       Default test
>       Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0

Comment: Esa excepción es común si lo que tratas de imprimir es null

Comment: Es importante agregues las etiquetas correspondientes a tu pregunta y aportes los datos necesarios, en tu pregunta habla de RemoteWebElement  pero en realidad el casting es AndroidElement , revisar [ask] y el [tour] del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

ya lo resolví lo hice de la siguiente manera:

```
RemoteWebElement ele = (RemoteWebElement) driver.findElement(By.xpath(Constantes.txtTipoDeDocumento));

System.out.prinln(ele.getString());
```

Comment: En la pregunta usas AndroidElement  no RemoteWebElement. Para que deseas imprimir el objeto RemoteWebElement?

Answer (score -1):

Debes convertir a string el texto que obtienes:

Cambia esta linea:

```
System.out.println(ele.getText());
```

Por esta:

```
System.out.println(ele.getText().toString);
```

Comment: Gracias por tu esfuerzo a contribuir, en este caso el OP no agrega la información necesaría, de hecho no es un label ni un EditText, además estas usando appium.

Comment: Si, estoy usando Appium, uso java y selenium webdriver, para un aplicativo.